# KeyError when using non-ASCII characters as keys in a python dictionary

Tags: python, keyerror

I have this function:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding=UTF-8

def filt(word):
    dic = {'á':'a','é':'e','í':'i','ó':'o','ú':'u'}
    new = ''
    for l in word:
        new = new + dic[l]
    return new
```

But when I call the function for some string (e.g. "árvore") and run the script, I get this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "filt.py", line 11, in
>   
>       print filt("árvore")   File "filt.py", line 8, in filt
>       new = new + dic[l] KeyError: '\xc3'

What's wrong?

Comment: For unicode string, you need `"u"` in front of the string: ex: `u'á'`, or `new = u''`.

Comment: which version of python are you using? On python 3 it works flowlessly by changing  dic[l] to dic.get(l,l)

Comment: Ok, your print call makes it obvious it's py2. Xin gave you the answer

Answer (score 3):

You should pass word as a unicode object, so the iteration is done on each unicode character:

```
def filt(word):
    dic = {u'á':'a', u'é':'e', u'í':'i', u'ó':'o', u'ú':'u'}
    new = ''
    for l in word:
        new = new + dic.get(l, l)
    return new

print(filt(u"árvore"))
#          ^
# arvore
```

Or use `word.decode('utf8')` before iterating on the string.

Remember to update your dictionary keys also, and return the original object using `dict.get` for items that are not dictionary keys.

Answer (score 0):

Encoding can be troublesome in [python-2](/questions/tagged/python-2). You should use `unicode` strings whenever there are any non-ascii characters involved:

```
def filt(word):
    dic = dict(zip(u'áéíóú', u'aeiou'))
    return u''.join(dic.get(l, l) for l in word)

> filt(u'árvore')
'arvore'
```

Using `dict.get(key, default)` avoids key errors for all the the characters that are not in `dic`.